# Is it possible to do multiple actions per commit in an interactive rebase?

Tags: git, interactive, rebase

When doing an interactive `rebase` (`$ git rebase -i`) there are many commands available. Two examples are `edit` and `squash`.

Putting a command beside a commit will perform that command on that particular commit, however sometimes I would like to perform two actions on a particular commit. Such as editing, then squashing.

Is this possible without running the interactive rebase twice?

Answer (score 0):

No, although when you run a squash, you are given the option to edit the commit message of the commits involved in the squash. So both the actions are usually not necessary

Edit:

You can use the edit option to actually edit the commit. The rebase will stop at the commit and it is possible to edit the contents, or even split the commit into two commits

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Comment: Yep, that functionality is included in the squash command. However I was asking about the edit command, where you are able to edit the content of a commit, not just the message.

Comment: After seeing your edit, yes they are the functionalities of the two commands I gave as examples. However they don't help provide an answer to the question put forward.